# Render cinematic sequence to target via scene capture 2d

Tags: unreal-engine4, render-to-texture

I've made a lengthy cinematic and instead of having it fill the screen I'd like to display it on a render target via scene capture 2d (a la sitting at the movie). I'm probably missing something but I don't see a way to do this. Thought it would be trivial to pass the mastercam render to a target.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried already.

Comment: I tried parenting my "portal" mesh w/ scene capture 2d to the mastercam but its incompatible.